# Why chrome think that xlsx is zip?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input, antd

everyone and sorry for my English)

So, i tried to create button with React and antd (but i think it's not important). I create Upload with property accept = ".zip", but when i tried to upload file with chrome i see that i can choose xlsx, pptx, docs, etc and zip ofk. In mozilla everything working correctly.

```
<Upload **props here** accept={".zip"}/>
```

I tried do it with

```
<Upload **props here** accept={"application/zip"}/>
```

Nothing...

Thanks for help

UPD: I have the same problem in Opera, is it bug of Chromium Engine?

Comment: Because those are actually zip files. Are you on linux?

Comment: Mac OS X... Unix)

Comment: XLSX (and other modern Office file formats) is actually just a zip file with a different extension. Try it - open one in a ZIP reader. So the browser likely tries to detect the type of file, and in the absence of any info from the O/S about it being an Office file (and thus having an Excel-specific mime type) it likely decides it can understand it as a Zip file, and assigns it the Zip mime type. I don't know exactly what goes on but that seems like a logical thing for the browser to do.

Comment: Of course, different browsers (or potentially the same browser on different O/Ses, or with different software installed on the same O/S) may have different capabilities to detect known file types. I doubt there is very much you can do about it, apart from adding some more rules to disallow specific file extensions. If you think it shouldn't behave like that, try raising a bug with the maintainers of the browser engine, but they may feel it's either intentional, or not worth working round, or impossible for some reason.

Comment: Microsoft and ZIP... Why not RAR, Microsoft?

Comment: Apart from any technical differences (which I'm not qualified to comment on) a big reason is probably because RAR is a proprietary format whose copyright is owned by a different company, whereas the ZIP format has been in the public domain since the 1980s.

Comment: There is an [open bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=646941&can=1&start=0&num=100&q=accept%20extension%20zip%20input&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=). Feel free to "star" it.